# Why does this code produce different output from time to time?

Tags: c++

Compiler:

```
➜ ~ /usr/bin/c++ --version
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.8)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <exception>
#include <cstdlib>


void f() {
    try {
        throw std::runtime_error("Exception message.");
    } catch(std::runtime_error& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        throw;
    }
}


int main() {
    using namespace std;
    try {
        f();
    } catch(std::exception& e) {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
        terminate();
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I found out that if i get rid of the "terminate()" in my catch it would work but i am not sure why that is?

There are three outputs that are produced randomly:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error: Exception message.
Exception message.
Exception message.


Exception message.
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error: Exception message.
Exception message.


Exception message.
Exception message.
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error: Exception message.
```

*P.S. Sorry, maybe for the incorrect question, I'm a beginner.*

Comment: Are you asking why the order of the lines in the output changes?

Comment: At a guess: the "terminating with ..." message is printed to `stderr` while your "Exception message" print goes to `stdout`. If you redirect one to the other like `./my_program 2>&1`, the results should be deterministic.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica what now?

Comment: @Botje it was suggestion to move comment down as a regular answer.

Comment: Oh. All I see is a row of boxes with "2B63" inside (which I now looked up and is a unicode arrow pointing down). That makes sense :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters, your regular `cout` print goes to `stdout`, but the "Terminating with ..." message goes to `stderr`.
What you observe stems from the fact that your terminal (or IDE) is reading these two output channels and presenting them in one place.
Depending on what algorithm your terminal/IDE uses to merge these two streams, it can happen that the `stderr` message appears in the places you notice.

If you instead point the streams toward the same file descriptor, your OS will take care of the merging. Run your program as follows:

```
./my_program 2>&1
```

Now your terminal will show the messages sequentially with no chance for accidental reordering.